# RestTemplate returns null response

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am using a url to call the server side code through RestTemplate which returns a json object and I am casting the response into the corresponding POJO of the json object. But, every call to the server returns null response. Below is my code:

```
String fullHost = <host>;
MyResponseObject responseObject1 = new RestTemplate().getForObject(fullHost, MyResponseObject .class);
```

I also have added the method converter(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) in my client class. Can someone please give me any clue on what might be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you do the same over a browser rest client? Also, is this http or https?

Comment: when I do it on a browser, it works fine, I get a response indicating it succeeded. it is http.